# Deleting a row and getting back to the current page Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Hi I'm trying to delete a row in my pivottable called projecttasks and then to go back the current page where I was deleted a projecttask. Here is a screenshot of the view in my browser:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZgLt.png

Deleting a row in the projecttasks table works, but getting back to the current view  doesn't yet work. I know why that happens. It's because of my $project_id variable that has no value in my ProjectTaskController. But I did see the value in the view before I had deleted a row in projecttasks table.

I will show you first the error page that I see on my browser:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaqEZ.png

Well that isn't clear for me, but I do see that the url looks strange. Because it has double forward slashes. It looks like this:

```
http://localhost/offerteTool/public/user/projects//edit
```

I will show you now what I had tried:

form.blade.php (view):

```
@foreach ($project->projecttask as $pt)
              <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ $pt->task['task_name'] }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{-- {{  $project->id }} --}}
            <input type="hidden" name="projectId" value="{{$project->id}}"/>
                {{--    {{Form::hidden('id', $project->id)}} --}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ Form::text('hour', $pt->hour, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'hour')) }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ Form::text('hour_salary', $pt->hour_salary, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'hour_salary')) }}
                </td>
                <td>
                {{ Form::text('total_salary', $pt->total_salary, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'total_salary', 'disabled')) }}
                {{--    {{ Form::text('total_salary', $project->total_salary, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'total_salary', 'disabled')) }}--}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle selDelete" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <input id="check1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="check" >
                            <span class="caret-hover caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selDelete" role="menu">
                            <li><a href= "{{ route('user.projecttasks.destroy',array( $pt->id )) }}" data-method="delete" >Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                     </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
```

ProjectTasksController.php :

```
<?php 
public function destroy($id)
{  $project_id=Input::get('projectId');
    //die(print_r($project_id)); //there is no value in $project_id
    Projecttask::destroy($id);

    //$project = Project::find($project_id);
    return Redirect::route('user.projects.edit', array($project_id));

}
```

And then we go to routes.php:

```
<?php
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'user', 'before'=>'auth'),function(){
    Route::resource('usergroups', 'UsergroupsController');
    Route::resource('orders', 'OrdersController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
    Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');

    Route::get('orders/destroy/{id}',array('as'=>'user.orders.destroy', 'uses'=>'OrdersController@destroy'));
    Route::get('users/destroy/{id}',array('as'=>'user.users.destroy', 'uses'=>'UsersController@destroy'));
    Route::get('projects/destroy/{id}',array('as'=>'user.projects.destroy', 'uses'=>'ProjectsController@destroy'));
    Route::get('projecttasks/destroy/{id}',array('as'=>'user.projecttasks.destroy', 'uses'=>'ProjectTasksController@destroy'));

    });
```

and then we run the edit() method in ProjectsController.php:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $project = Project::find($id);

        return View::make('user.projects.edit', compact('project'));
    }
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Why are you redeclaring the destroy endpoints? They are already created by your resource controllers.

Comment: Because even if I use  "Route::resource('projecttasks', 'ProjectTasksController');"    then I couldn't use:     "<li><a href= "{{ route('user.projecttasks.destroy',array( $pt->id )) }}" data-method="delete" >Delete</a></li>".   It was always going to  "user/projecttasks/{projecttasks}"   instead of  "user/projecttasks/destroy/{id}"